# Find if the following limit exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

This might me a simple problem, but I want to see if I got it right

Given $$F(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{b}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}&  \text{if }x-3y=0\\
y+3&\text{ if }x-3y\neq 0
\end{array}\right.$$

Does the $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} F(x,y)$ exist?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;x=y\implies x-3y=-2y\neq0\implies F(y,y)=y+3\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}3\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;x=3y\iff x-3y=0\implies F(3y,y)=\frac{3y^2}{10y^2}\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}\frac3{10}\end{align*}$$